# How to avoid multiple for loops when traversing all the nested child objects in Java?

Tags: java, performance, loops, for-loop

I know that traversal through objects in nested loops is a bad practice. I have come across a situation like this and having a hard time to find a way to avoid the nested loops.

I have an item list. Each item can have several locations.

```
> Item01 -> location01, location02, location03
> Item02 -> Location04, location05
....
```

My code is something like below

```
        List<Item> itemList = getItemList();
        RenderItem renderItem = new RenderItem();
        List<RenderItem> renderItemList = new ArrayList<RenderItem>();

        for (Item item: itemList){

            for (ItemLocation itemLocation : item.getLocations() ){

                renderItem = new RenderItem();
                renderItem.setItem(item);
                renderItem.setLocation(itemLocation);
                renderItemList.add(renderItem);

            }
        }
```

I need to traverse all the location and create a renderItemList.

How can I get rid of the nested loops? what strategies should I use? Please advice. [Note: I can only use Java 7]

Comment: Why do you want to avoid nested loops? You can use a `while` loop with an `Iterator`, but that's essentially the same.

Comment: With Java 8, you would do it with Streams. With Java 7, you can do the equivalent with Guava. Also, a possible alternative is to explain your manager that the current version of Java is java 11.

Comment: if your `getLocations()` returns a List -> [addAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll(java.util.Collection))?

Comment: @MCEmperor you are saying, this is the correct way to do it ?

Comment: The only changes I would make in Java 7: `List<RenderItem> renderItemList = new ArrayList<>();` and `RenderItem renderItem = new RenderItem();`. Plus maybe a constructor `new RenderItem(item, itemLocation)`. The code is fine.

Comment: I don't think the performance can get any better than this. You need all the locations so you have to loop through all. Using another style of coding doesn't make that much of a difference.

Comment: @JoopEggen thanks for the information

Comment: @Harshakj89 This is one of the correct ways to do it, I think. I would tweak your model a little (for example, I would maybe replace the no-args constructor with one accepting an `Item` and a `Location`), but this is fine. Remember: two for-loops is fine, but if you need more nesting, you'd better double-check your design.

Answer (score 0):

> traversal through objects in nested loops is a bad practice

`Nested Loop` is a bad practice **IF AND ONLY IF** there is another optimal solution which can reduce Time complexity from `O(N^2)` or `O(A*B)` to `O(N)`

BUT in your case
You need to touch all `Locations` in all `Items`
So no problem

Answer (score 0):

By increasing space complexity you can reduce the time complexity. If you can maintain another ArrayList just to save Locations it will require more memory but then you can directly loop through the Locations ArrayList with single loop.

Comment: How does it reduce time complexity? Instead of `i` collections with size of `j` you end up with a single one with size of `i*j`. You're just flattening those collections.

Comment: Yup, agreed, Number of iterations will remain same but time complexity will be reduced from O(N^2) to O(N). As the original questions was to find a way to do it in single loop, I gave the way :).

Comment: In both cases you will have to iterate over all elements exactly once. Total time to achive the effect will be the same in both cases.

Comment: Its still O(n^2). just because you merge them it does not change the complexity, that's not how it works. The complexity is related to the input size. so if you have i*j which is approximated to n*n you have n². You could now say n² = m which you use to describe the flattened array. But you cannot say its O(n) because its realted to the size of the inputs). If you name it m the end its still m=n*n. So if n increases for 1 we have (n+1)*n = m+n. So if we inrease the input by one it adds n steps no which is the definition of n², no matter how you name it. But you cannot name it